# I am getting duplicate nodes on a treeview

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an FTP program with a Treeview control to show the local files. Whenever I close and reopen a node, it duplicates the list of files and folders. I know why it is happening, but not sure how to fix the issue. It occurs because when reopening a node runs the `tvLocal_BeforeExpand` code each time.

```
{            
  InitializeComponent();
}
FileExplorer fe = new FileExplorer();
    string strLocalFolder = string.Empty;
    string strRemoteHost = string.Empty;

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fe.CreateTree(tvLocal);

    }

    private void tvLocal_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode node = fe.EnumerateDirectory(e.Node);
    }
```

I am using the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;


namespace FileExplorer_TreeView
{
    /* Class  :FileExplorer
     * Author : Chandana Subasinghe
     * Date   : 10/03/2006
     * Discription : This class use to create the tree view and load 
     *               directories and files in to the tree
     *          
     */
    class FileExplorer
    {
    public FileExplorer()
    {

    }

    /* Method :CreateTree
     * Author : Chandana Subasinghe
     * Date   : 10/03/2006
     * Discription : This is use to creat and build the tree
     *          
     */

    public bool CreateTree(TreeView treeView)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;

        try
        {
            // Create Desktop
            TreeNode desktop = new TreeNode();
            desktop.Text = "Desktop";
            desktop.Tag = "Desktop";
            desktop.Nodes.Add("");
            treeView.Nodes.Add(desktop);
            // Get driveInfo
            foreach (DriveInfo drv in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {

                TreeNode fChild = new TreeNode();
                if (drv.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom)
                {
                    fChild.ImageIndex = 1;
                    fChild.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
                }
                else if (drv.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
                {
                    fChild.ImageIndex = 0;
                    fChild.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
                }
                fChild.Text = drv.Name;
                fChild.Nodes.Add("");
                treeView.Nodes.Add(fChild);
                returnValue = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            returnValue = false;
        }
        return returnValue;

    }

    /* Method :EnumerateDirectory
     * Author : Chandana Subasinghe
     * Date   : 10/03/2006
     * Discription : This is use to Enumerate directories and files
     *          
     */
    public TreeNode EnumerateDirectory(TreeNode parentNode)
    {

        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo rootDir;

            // To fill Desktop
            Char [] arr={'\\'};
            string [] nameList=parentNode.FullPath.Split(arr);
            string path = "";

            if (nameList.GetValue(0).ToString() == "Desktop")
            {
                path = SpecialDirectories.Desktop+"\\";

                for (int i = 1; i < nameList.Length; i++)
                {
                    path = path + nameList[i] + "\\";
                }

                rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            }
         // for other Directories
            else
            {

                rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(parentNode.FullPath + "\\");
            }

            parentNode.Nodes[0].Remove();
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in rootDir.GetDirectories())
            {

                TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
                node.Text = dir.Name;
                node.Nodes.Add("");
                parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
            }
            //Fill files
            foreach (FileInfo file in rootDir.GetFiles())
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
                node.Text = file.Name;
                node.ImageIndex = 2;
                node.SelectedImageIndex = 2;
                parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
            }



        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO : 
        }

        return parentNode;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code in `CreateTree` and `EnumerateDirectory` when you add new nodes, it seems to me that the nodes that have not been expanded yet have a single child node that has an empty text. You can use this information to determine if you need to expand again:

```
private void tvLocal_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    bool never_expanded =
        e.Node.Nodes.Count == 1
        && e.Node.Nodes[0].Text == "";

    if(never_expanded)
    {
        TreeNode node = fe.EnumerateDirectory(e.Node);
    }
}
```

By the way, you don't seem to use the return value (`TreeNode node`). If this is the case, then you can simply remove it and just invoke `fe.EnumerateDirectory(e.Node);`